# Scheduled FTP data import

Tags: cron-job, scheduling

In my extension, I can now import some data (contact and membership) from a csv file through a specific download form.

I need now to create a scheduled import, that search, once a day, a folder for the csv presence. The php with the internal routed URL is now ready but I don't know how to periodically call it:

- calling the routed page URL, ask me for credentials before executing
- create a scheduled job, needs, from what I understand, a specific API

How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create an API with `civix generate:api`. More information can be found under *Add an API function* in the [Civix page](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-api) of the Developer Guide.